# Can you lend me a hand with this word counting code?

Tags: c

This code don't count words properly. I don't know if it is wrong on the for or what. Need help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int count_p(char sentence[100]) {
    int i, m = 1;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
        if (sentence[i] == ' ') {
            m += 1;
        }
    }
    return(m);
}

void main() {
    char s[100];
    int p;
    printf("Sentence here: ");
    scanf("%s", &s[50]);
    p = count_p(sentence);
    printf("Words: %d", p); 
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `%s` in `scanf` stops reading when it found a whitespace. Therefore, `' '` won't appear in `s` unless it was there as indeterminate value in uninitialized variable.

You can use `fgets` to read a whole line.

Here is a fixed code that also checks for end of the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int count_p(char sentence[100]) {
    int i, m = 1;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 100 && sentence[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (sentence[i] == ' ') {
            m += 1;
        }
    }
    return(m);
}

int main(void) {
    char s[100];
    int p;
    printf("Sentence here: ");
    fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
    p = count_p(s);
    printf("Words: %d", p); 
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But i don't underestand  fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);

Comment: @Congelador10 please read the documentation [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html). And if you can't use it, check my answer.

Comment: Ok I underestood that. Now why you put && sentence[i] != '\0'

Comment: To stop iterating at the end of string. Otherwise, it will read indeterminate (uninitialized) value and may count spaces that  are accidentaly there.

Answer (score 0):

You see `&s[50]` means that you pass a pointer to the *51-th* element of `s`, you then try to access `s` from the beginning but, the first 50 characters in `s` were not yet initialized, this leads to undefined behavior.

Also, your loop from `0` to `99` will have the same issue since you might input a string of less than 100 characters, in that case you would be accessing uninitialized data too.

You can fix your program by changing this

```
scanf("%s", &s[50]);
```

to

```
scanf("%99s", s);
```

and then

```
for (i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
```

to

```
for (i = 0 ; s[i] != '\0' ; i++) {
```

because `scanf()` will append a `'\0'` to make the array a valid [c](/questions/tagged/c) [string](/questions/tagged/string), that's also the reason for the `"%99s"`.

Another problem is that, if you want white space characters not to make `scanf()` stop reading, you need a different specifier, because `"%s"` stops at the first white space character, this is a suggestion

```
scanf("%99[^\n]", s);
```

Or you can do as @[MikeCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33217890/1983495) suggested and go with `fgets()`. But be careful with the trailing `'\n'` in case of `fgets()`.

And finally, altough highly unlikely in this situation, `scanf()` might fail. To indicate success it returns the number of specifiers actually matched, thus it might indicate partial success too. It's fairly common to see the return value of `scanf()` ignored, and it's very bad when you have a `"%d"` specifier for example because then the correspoinding parameter might be accessed before initializing it.

Comment: Why there is no need on putting "&" on scanf("%99s", s); on the s.

Comment: Because `&` is used to take the address of a variable `s` is already a pointer with the address to the first element. And if you must use it, don't you think it should be `&s[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%s", &s[50]);
```

Not a correct way to take input and writing at index which is out of bound. Do this instead -

```
scanf("%99[^\n]", s);     // this will read 99 characters and until '\n' is encountered
```

In `main` you function call is incorrect -

```
   p = count_p(sentence);        // sentence is not declares in main
```

Call like this -

```
   p = count_p(s);               // pass s instead of sentence to function
```

Also in function `count_p` change ccondition in `for` loop as -

```
size_t i;
size_t len=strlen(s); 
for (i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
```

Comment: Still getting same error. If I put 3 words, it counts them as 5.

Comment: @Congelador10 I have updated the answer . Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `scanf("%s", &s[50]);` is in correct in your situation.Since you want to enter a sentence separated by spaces,the correct way of doing it is :

```
scanf(" %99[^\n]s",sentence);
```

That will prevent buffer overflow and allow space between words.Also your program does not seem to count words correctly if the `sentence` has consecutive whitespaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int count_p(char *sentence);

void main()
{
    char sentence[100];

    printf("Sentence here: ");

    scanf(" %99[^\n]s",sentence);

    int p = count_p(sentence);

    printf("Words: %d", p);

    printf("\n");
}

int count_p(char *sentence)
{
    int len = strlen(sentence);

    int x = 0 , wordCount = 0; 

    for( int n = 0 ; n < len ; n++ )
    {
        x++;

        if( sentence[n] == ' ' )
            x = 0;

        if( x == 1 )
            wordCount++;
    }
    return wordCount;
}
```